# Calling an add on a list from a getter of an object does not work as expected

Tags: java, oop

So I have an object with a list field and I am accessing the list using a getter.

```
public class Customers{
    private List<String> names;

    public Customers(List<String> names){
        this.names = names;
    }

    public List<String> getNames(){
        return names;
    }

    public String toString(){
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(String name: this.names){
             sb.append("Customer:");
             sb.append(name);
             sb.append("\n");
         }
    }
}
```

I then use add to add an element to the list calling the getter.

```
customer = new Customer(myCustomers);
customer.getNames().add("Tupac");
customer.getNames().add("Abba");
```

After adding a bunch of elements like that, when I print customer.toString() it only shows

```
Customer: Tupac
```

Why is add not working as expected?

Comment: Could you provide a bigger code sample please? It's hard to deduct  missing details.

Comment: The code you've posted won't compile.  You aren't returning anything from your `toString()` method, which declares a return type of `String`.  Not to mention other typos such as `Customer`/`Customers`.  Please post your *actual* code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your posted sample code has syntax errors.  Fix those and the code does what you're wanting.

```
public class Customers {

    private List<String> names;

    public Customers(List<String> names) {
        this.names = names;
    }

    public List<String> getNames() {
        return names;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String name : this.names) {
            sb.append("Customer:");
            sb.append(name);
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Customers customers = new Customers(new ArrayList());
    customers.getNames().add("Tupac");
    customers.getNames().add("Abba");
    System.out.println(customers);
}
```

Results:

```
Customer:Tupac
Customer:Abba
```

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, it is highly possible, that OP either lied to us (because *"After adding a bunch of elements like that, when I print customer.toString() it only shows "* can't be true) or posted the wrong code (because the code in the question isn't "complete"). This is very disappointing. But thanks to you @Shar1er80, good answer.